# travel from Dublin airport to Direct Ferries Terminal

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, dublin, dub

Will arrive in Dublin Airport at 10:20AM and need to find our way to the Direct Ferries Terminal. Our ferry leaves at 2:30PM and should arrive an hour before departure. What would be the best mode of transportation? Cheapest?

Comment: Direct Ferries is not an Operator. Check your Operator. Examples are Irish Ferries, Stena Line and P&O.

Answer (score 3):

The distance from the airport to the ferry port is about 12 km. [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Dublin-Airport-DUB/Dublin-Port) lists the options. Bus is the least expensive, with the Dublin bus about €3.50, and the Airlink bus €7. While both indicate it takes, 15 minutes, I’ve found it can more like 25-30. A taxi will be as quick, and cost about €20-25. There is a [dedicated shuttle service](http://ie.jayride.com/) through you can book.